# Way to connect to dav without mounting as drive?

Tags: backup, webdav

I need to backup data which are accessible over webdav. Is threre a way to connect to it witout mounting it as an drive?
My preferable way to do it would be an script I can run as cronjob to automatically backup the data.

Answer (score 0):

[Davix](https://davix.web.cern.ch/davix/docs/devel/) is perhaps what you're looking for or [Cadaver](http://www.webdav.org/cadaver/) - long unmaintained and I'm not even sure it supports modern protocols.